# Git clone with SK-ED25519 Key

Tags: git, gitlab, openssh

I try to connect to an Git(lab) Server via Git CLI Tool.
Previous i created a sk-ed25519 Key with help of a Yubikey Security Token.
This Key is useable with SSH Services in general.
Only git fails with this Error:
Did i miss something?

```
C:\Users\testuser\test>git clone git@gitlab.domain.local:usernamegitlab/testproject.git
    Cloning into 'testproject'...
    Confirm user presence for key ED25519-SK SHA256:4oyWx+4CK...................1pcwBw
    sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "d:/path/privatekey": invalid format
```

edit1:\
In my WSL Setup everything is working like expected.

```
git version 2.25.1
```

On windows git version `2.34.1.windows.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in Version 2.40.